# Why can g++ 5.4 not compile this compile-time prime number code?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, constexpr, compile-time-constant

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int N> class Prime
{ // generate N prime numbers at compile time
public:
    unsigned int arr[N]{};
    constexpr Prime() {
        int k=0;
        for(unsigned int i=2; k<N; i++) {
            bool isPrime = true;
            for(int j=0; j<k; j++) {
                if(arr[j] > i/2) break;
                if(i % arr[j] == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime) arr[k++] = i;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    Prime<50000> prime; // if 50000->5000, ok
    for(auto& a : prime.arr) cout << a << ' ';
}
```

G++ fails to compile this code. It spends ages trying to compile, uses lots of memory, and finally just crashes.

If I make the number 50000 smaller, or get rid of `constexpr`, it compiles. But I want to use bigger arrays to save time.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: situation is like this. compiler takes forever to compile. using lots of memories and finally just crashes..

Comment: You're asking gcc to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 50000, itself, using metaprogramming. Quite impressive, but this is not what compilers are meant to be used for. You, sir/m'am, won the Internets today.

Comment: ... Really, this deserves an upvote just for the awesomeness ...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- maybe we can finally put to rest all the arguments about if compiled Java or C++ is fater

Comment: Damn right. I'd like to see a Java compiler try to do something like this. Good. fracking. luck.

Comment: @Parker: ...And next time you'll write a program that computes the answer to "The Question of Life the Universe and Everything" *at compile time* and expect it to finish compiling while you are making yourself a cup of coffee?

Comment: @AnT If you try that g++ fails to compile it, but offers to build a more powerful compiler that is capable of doing the task.  And it shall be called... clang

Comment: @AnT Coffee? More like a drink that tastes almost, but not quite, exactly unlike tea.

Comment: In 7 and a half million years there will still be people using C89 because the vender hasn't got around to supporting C99 yet

Comment: The code compiles given any number without any problem, but it is crashing at run time.

Comment: works on Clang 3.4 and higher

Comment: If you actually do need the first 50000 prime numbers I'd suggest to compute or download them offline and store them in a constexpr variable. This is kust wasted compiletime.

Comment: GCC clearly uses too much memory for this, but this is still a total waste of time and electricity. The primes aren't going to change, you don't need to recalculate them every time you compile. Write a (non-compile-time!) program to print them, save that in a header file, and include it in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Quality of Implemention (QoI) matter. From the [**draft Standard**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4640.pdf)

> **Annex B (informative) Implementation quantities [implimits]**
>
> 1 Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably
>   limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
>   Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
>   This documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to
>   compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say
>   that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> 2 The limits may constrain quantities that include those described
>   below or others. The bracketed number following each quantity is
>   recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these
>   quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> (2.38) — Recursive constexpr function invocations [512].
>
> (2.39) — Full-expressions evaluated within a core constant expression
>   [1 048 576].

Your algorithm exceeds the limit of full-expressions evaluated within a core constant expression. Note that gcc does exceed the minimum requirement since your loop scales as `1/2 * N^2` and gcc compiles it for `N = 5,000`. I haven't been able to find the documented hard limit for gcc. Unfortunately, and unlike clang which has `-fconstexpr-steps`, you cannot override the number of constexpr evaluations for gcc.

**Conclusion**: submit a performance report to gcc or use clang (for which your example does compile).